# stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth makes image Blurry

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hello i have an image such as this
[image]

And i would think that it could stretch just fine. Its 17px wide and 30 px tall.

I just want to be able to stretch it horizontally. But this is what i end up with when i stretch it.
[image]

With out stretching it...[image]

Maybe I'm being picky about these corners but it just seems like it should work a little better than it is.

Any help would be awesome!

```
int textWidth = [text length] * 10;

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(32.50f, 14.5f, 40.0f, 30.0f);

    UIImage* img = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"screen_displayer_rounded.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:8 topCapHeight:0];
    UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

    [imgView setImage:img];    

    //[imgView addSubview:label];
    NSLog(@"imge %@", imgView.subviews);

    [self addSubview:imgView];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should preserve at least 5 pixels horizontally and 6 vertically. Therefore use 5x6 as your caps instead 4x0 (btw, 0 means stretch the whole image). This way, iOS will stretch your image using the pixels sixth and seventh (marked in red below).

[image: corner]

Comment: sorry posted wrong code, it is normally 8 which would make the right 8 which makes 16 so 1 px left over for stretching, still doesnt work. same thing as above

Comment: Can you try adding rect =CGRectIntegral(rect); ? positioning in a fraction of a pixel sometimes leads to blurry graphics. And replace the caps 8x0 with 8x6.

Comment: CGRectIntegral truncates the dimensions to integer coordinates. If you try to place a image in half a pixel (32.5 in your code above), iOS emulates that position using blurry antialising. And 6 instead 0 is to preserve a vertical cap.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your image in Photoshop, it looks like your horizontal and vertical rounded corners are 5px and 6px respectively. So, the following line should be as follows;

```
UIImage* img = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"screen_displayer_rounded.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:6];
```

Comment: Look closely at the top example, its not being stretched in any way, the corners are just blurry, even if i set the width to 10000, the corners stay the exact same, just blurred...

Comment: Hey again James, in your updated question, the topCapHeight remains at 0. Just to verify, did you try setting that to 6?